# Deleting Grease Pencil Keyframes

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, timeline

I recently started working with the Grease Pencil and can't seem to figure out how to tweak and edit the keyframes of Grease Pencil. I want to be able to move them around on the timeline, but I'm not sure where to do this.

Normal action-based animations have the action editor where I can move the keyframes around. The grease pencil doesn't appear to have anything like this. Additionally, when you delete all of the strokes on keyframes, the markers don't disappear on the timeline. This is going to get messy fast if I can't fix this.

I'd rather not have to delete entire layers just to remove markers on one frame of the timeline.

To be concise:

[image]

How do I remove these?

Thank you!

Comment: I just discovered how to delete the keyframes. You can do it from the tool menu that can be accessed by pressing n by pressing the X beside the frame lock button. But is there a way to move the keyframes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Dope Sheet editor to shift or delete the keyframes for the grease pencil:

[image]

Comment: Yep, literally just found this as you posted it. Spent a few hours trying to figure it out and as soon as I post a question on here I find it. Funny how that works, haha! Thank you for the help!